# How can I save .docx file data into modal table like Excel sheet using django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

How can I save MS Word `.docx` file data into modal table like Excel sheet `row wise, column wise` using django

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from docx import opendocx, getdocumenttext
from cStringIO import StringIO


def document_to_text(filename, file_path):
    cmd = ['antiword', file_path]
    p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    return stdout.decode('ascii', 'ignore')

print document_to_text('your_file_name','your_file_path')
```